# Best solution delivered by optaplanner using dynamically configured times

Tags: optaplanner

Hello optaplanner community

I find myself testing the answers that optimization gives and I interpret that something is wrong. I am using dynamic configurations where the user decides the time to spend on the optimization. As I understand it, the longer the time, the better the solution, but this is not the case.

I have a problem with 3 vehicles and 30 visits, when I solve it with 2 seconds I get 12 visits (customers) unserved and I attend 18 visits satisfactorily.

With the same problem, that is, the same 3 vehicles and 30 visits, with the same loads and time windows, with 5 seconds it leaves me 14 visits unserved.

I expected that for 5 seconds I would get at least the same response as for 2 seconds and if a better solution could be found, in terms of fewer visits unserved.

1- Am I right? or is it a mistake on my part, and such a scenario can happen.
I hope that if the maximum number of entities that optaplanner can process is 18, then for both 2 seconds and 5 seconds it will give me the same result or improve it if possible.

2- On the other hand, on performance and optimization issues. What would be the recommended time ranges according to the amount of views to process? That is, for example, how long can I configure it when I have 100 visits, how long when I have 300 visits, one thousand, 5 thousand, etc.
I think it should be done configurable because for example if more than a thousand visits require 30 seconds, 500 visits can be processed in less time. For that reason I would like to know what are the reasonable times handled by optaplanner by scales, up to k entities that you should take into account.

3- And also before what volume of entities is advisable to modify the configuration properties (config.xml), such as heuristic construction algorithms, etc

Answer (score 0):

I have a very complex scheduling implementation that is not optimized in terms of code but I doubt that it will improve much more than 15-20% execution time. For 10 employees and 4 weeks of scheduling, it takes 20 min to meet all the hard requirements and an additional 20 min to meet the medium and get pretty far with soft. Why is 2 or 5 seconds interesting? I do not think there are any limits in OptaPlanner apart from what Java can assign values for :) I looked into the solverconfig but it was doing just fine with default settings.

Comment: I have optimized in terms of code and with respect to optaplanner it processes me 500, 1000, entities in a matter of seconds when it is capable of attending to all visits. However, when the capacities of the vehicles are lower than the demands of the visits or it is impossible to satisfy all the TW of the clients, apparently the space of search is increased or it is more difficult to him to assign certain entities, therefore it takes more time in returning the best solution, here it delays up to 10min ... that depends on the challenges also ...

Comment: ... now I try to optimize by trying with other algorithms and configurations of heuristic construction and local search, and perhaps variant to assign these visits not served in fictitious vehicles, with the aim that optaplanner improve the response time...Yes thanks, I looked at the solverconfig and made some changes for my problem, thanks for the help